# Android - EditText with assistance

Tags: android, android-edittext

is possible to create EditText that when i start entering letters will give suggestions for words that are on the database?

and if yes who can i make something like that?

Comment: Do you mean like autofill ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use `AutoCompleteTextView` instead of `EditText`. Then, you need to set the adapter for the `AutoCompleteTextView`, which is the words that are on your database.

```
AutoCompleteTextView ac = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.yourAutoCompleteTextView);
ac.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, youArrayFromDatabase));
```

Hope it helps!